# Is it possible to use pgp_sym_encrypt on JSONB Key value?

Tags: postgresql, encryption, jsonb

I have been looking all over, trying to find the answer to this question but I am unable to find an answer.

The main question, can you use pgp_sym_encrypt on a JSON array columns. So for example let say I have a form post that comes back in by req.body as

```
[{
id: 22,
fname: "jim", 
lname: "smith",
email: "someemail@email.com"
}]
```

Now, I want to store this as JSONB in postgres, however lets say I want to encrypt the email address using pgp_sym_encrypt, is it possible to do that?

We have used pgp_sym_encrypt on regular columns however we were looking at JSONB to possibly store the data as just JSON however there may be times we need to encrypt part of the JSON object for say PII, however still would like the ability to search on that field using pgp_sym_decrypt

I'm not sure if what we are thinking is supported, or maybe its a bad use case as we cant seem to find anything specifically tailored to this use case. We have seen a few post on SO but they don't really go into the how you would do this on a JSONB column type or if its even possible.

We don't want the full object encrypted, just parts of it but when pulling the data out, say via an API we would want the value decrypted, mainly just want it to be encrypted at rest in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an interesting question.

I've done a few tests on my local PostgreSQL 13.1 installation and I have it working:

1. Create some sample data:

```sql
create table test_jsonb_crypto (id serial primary key, jsonb_col jsonb);
```

```sql
insert into test_jsonb_crypto (jsonb_col) VALUES('{"data1": {"data2": "test"}}');
```

```
 id |           jsonb_col            
----+--------------------------------
  1 | {"data1": {"data2": "test"}}
```

2. Encrypt a value:

```sql
update test_jsonb_crypto set jsonb_col = jsonb_set(jsonb_col, '{"data1", "data2"}', ('"'||encode(pgp_sym_encrypt(jsonb_col->'data1'->>'data2', 'pwd'), 'hex')::varchar||'"')::jsonb) WHERE id = 1;
```

```sql
select * from test_jsonb_crypto;
```

```
id |                                                                              jsonb_col                                                                               
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"data1": {"data2": "c30d04070302b82d9fc1ff9d6ff37fd2350104dc859747a39d4cf8f61a1c72cb1bfe7e25556185e8347a5e74dace36cecc08a1b115977b5cc0c9ccc4e0bfc46e71f20bb763cd"}}
```

3. Get/use the original value:

```sql
select pgp_sym_decrypt(decode(jsonb_col->'data1'->>'data2', 'hex'), 'pwd') decrypted_value FROM test_jsonb_crypto WHERE id = 1;
```

```
 decrypted_value 
-----------------
 test
```

4. Insert encoded data with an INSERT statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_jsonb_crypto (jsonb_col) VALUES(jsonb_set('{"data1":{"data2":"insert_test"}}', '{"data1", "data2"}', ('"'||encode(pgp_sym_encrypt(('{"data1":{"data2":"insert_test"}}'::jsonb)->'data1'->>'data2', 'pwd'), 'hex')::varchar||'"')::jsonb));
```

In my tests I used the hexadecimal encoding because it is the less problematic one in combinaison with JSONB, other less storage expensive encodings might be tried.

Comment: in your code you are creating the record, then updating it, would there be a way to do it on the insert portion, or would we have to insert first, then query the result and update with the encrypted value?

We saw a similar approach on a SO comment, however it seemed a bit inefficient to insert, query and re-insert again.

Comment: Well... It is feasible but starts to look really ugly. I would definitely do it in 2 steps to keep it readable. Updating the answer

Comment: ok, million dollar question :D Does it even make sense then or would it be better served by structuring it so the table itself contained something like id, username,password,data then store the non pii as JSONB in the data column and then store username / password in its own column? Also, thanks for the feedback here it's really helpful.

Comment: There probably isn't a simple answer. It depends on how often you are expecting your JSON structure to change. Use JSON columns for data that is expected to change often. Use a dedicated column for data that is expected to be unchanged for a long time. 
So in your case I would say if you are expecting to have to encrypt a lot of fields, it might be worth investing some time into a module that will be able to encode whatever value of the JSON structure. If you are expecting to encrypt only a small subset of fields, just delete those fields from the JSON and store them in a dedicated column.